# QT signal and slot not working giving an error message

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals, qt-slot

I am new to Qt and trying to write signal and slot. Below is the code I was trying to run. with SLOT and SIGNAL keywords on "connect" function, it works fine. But I do not want to use SIGNAL and SLOT keywords on connect function, instead want to use a different approach.

```
  class MyWindow:public QMainWindow
  {
      Q_OBJECT
  public:
      MyWindow();
  };

  MyWindow::MyWindow()
  {
     QWidget *widget=new QWidget;
     QHBoxLayout *layout =new QHBoxLayout;
     QSpinBox *mySlide = new QSpinBox;
     mySlide->setRange(0,10);
     QLCDNumber *lcdNumber= new QLCDNumber;
     layout->addWidget(mySlide);
     layout->addWidget(lcdNumber);

       connect(mySlide,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),lcdNumber,SLOT(display(int)));
    // connect(mySlide, &QSpinBox::valueChanged,lcdNumber, &QLCDNumber::display);

      widget->setLayout(layout);
      setCentralWidget(widget);
   }
```

In above code, uncommented connect function works fine but commented connect function does not work. I am getting error "no matching function to call MyWindow::connect". Not sure what mistake I made here. I was following this article from qt.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-hellogl2-window-cpp.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that both the signal -- [`QSpinBox::valueChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#valueChanged) -- and the slot -- [`QLCDNumber::display`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlcdnumber.html#display-1) -- have multiple overloads for different argument types.  You have a few options.

1) Use a `static_cast` to disambiguate between the various signal and slot overloads...

```
connect(mySlide,
        static_cast<void(QSpinBox::*)(int)>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged),
        lcdNumber,
        static_cast<void(QLCDNumber::*)(int)>(&QLCDNumber::display));
```

or...

2) Just use a `lambda`...

```
connect(mySlide, static_cast<void(QSpinBox::*)(int)>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged),
        [lcdNumber](int value)
        {
          lcdNumber->display(value);
        });
```

Although using the `lambda still` requires a `static_cast` on the signal.

Comment: Thank you so much. It did work. But just curious to know why connect(mySlide, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),lcdNumber, &QLCDNumber::display) did not work. the first part is explicitly signal.

Comment: You can't mix and match between the various signal/slot syntaxes.  It's either all SIGNAL and SLOT syntax *or* the new pointer to member syntax.